# Rename a folder on server after GIT pull

Tags: git, rename

I have a web application that I am developing and using GIT as source control. The application is used by several clients with different domains. It has a folder which I called `web` on my local machine. However, that same folder is called `DOMAIN.NAME` on the servers and it, of course, changes from server to server.

Right now when I have to update the servers with the newest code, I SSH and do `git pull` which extracts the `web` folder on the server and then I rename it to the respective `DOMAIN.NAME` which corresponds to the server in question. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to automate this process somehow? Can I have a script/command that Git could execute to rename the folders for me or even better, read a variable from file stored on the server and name the respective folder to that value? Can I somehow create mapping that would connect `web` to the respective name of the folder on each server?

Any ideas are more than welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in git hooks, scripts that can run before or after events like commit, pull, push, etc: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Here's an example of a git hook that stops a commit if there are whitespace errors, from https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#local-hooks

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check if this is the initial commit
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
echo "pre-commit: About to create a new commit..."
against=HEAD
else
echo "pre-commit: About to create the first commit..."
against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi
# Use git diff-index to check for whitespace errors
echo "pre-commit: Testing for whitespace errors..."
if ! git diff-index --check --cached $against
then
echo "pre-commit: Aborting commit due to whitespace errors"
exit 1
else
echo "pre-commit: No whitespace errors :)"
exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I gather the `web` folder is part of a broader directory structure that your repo contains.  (If not, you could just move each server's clone to the appropriate directory; but I assume you'd have come up with that on your own.)

So the lightest-weight option would be, on each server, to make `DOMAIN.NAME` a symbolic link to `web`.  (I'm assuming the servers use a *NIX-style os and filesystem.)

If for some reason that isn't viable, you could look into git hooks.